# Loop over Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to loop over a Dropdownlist and write the value of the selected Item in a label.
I've done it before with a selection of Radio buttons but with the dropdownlist it won't work.
Now, some Code.

Here is the generated HTML Code Values are not interesting.

```
<select id="alternativeNumbers" name="alternativeNumbers">
   <option value="1_A">Text</option>
   <option value="2_B">Text</option>
   <option value="3_C">Text</option>
   <option value="4_D">Text</option>
   <option value="5_E">Text</option>
   <option value="6_F">Text</option>
</select>
```

The Code to bind the event to the Dropdownlist.

```
$(function () {
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByName("alternativeNumbers");
    $(dropdown ).change(function () {
        updateAlternativeDropdown();
    });
});
```

And finally the method which is called by the event. This should fill the labels.

```
function updateAlternativeDropdown() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByName("alternativeNumbers");
    var lengthDropDown = addAlternativeArticleNumberDropdown.length;
    for (var i=0; i < lengthDropDown; i++) 
    {
        //This alert is for the behavior of the output!
        alert(addAlternativeArticleNumberDropdown[i].value);
        if (addAlternativeArticleNumberDropdown[i].selected) {
            var valueOfDropdown = addAlternativeArticleNumberDropdown[i].value;
            var splittedValues = valueOfDropdown.split("_");
            document.getElementById("label1").innerText = splittedValues[0];
            document.getElementById("label2").innerText = splittedValues[1];
        }
    }
};
```

**I hope this is enough information, now the Problem / Current behavior:**

The method updateAlternativeDropdown() is called fine but then the alert inside the loop returns the value of first element, value of the selected element and this 3 times. (I guess because of the 6 elements in this element)

Furthermore because of this my if-statement isn't entered. Currently I#m kind of clueless where this problem comes from.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to iterate dropdown's options. You can access selected option like this:

```
dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value
```

Update your `updateAlternativeDropdown` function:

```js
function updateAlternativeDropdown() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("alternativeNumbers"),
        splittedValues = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value.split('_');
    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = splittedValues[0];
    document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = splittedValues[1];
}

$('#alternativeNumbers').change(updateAlternativeDropdown);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
label1: <span id="label1">-</span><br />
label2: <span id="label2">-</span><br />
<select id="alternativeNumbers" name="alternativeNumbers">
   <option value="1_A">Text</option>
   <option value="2_B">Text</option>
   <option value="3_C">Text</option>
   <option value="4_D">Text</option>
   <option value="5_E">Text</option>
   <option value="6_F">Text</option>
</select>
```

[working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/8e92d/)

Comment: That was unbelievable fast and works just fine.
You can't find a better Professional support. Thanks a lot.